# Can a singular noun follow zero-article?

Tags: articles, zero-article

I go to the bank, and ask:

> Which type of account should I open if I want to receive money from my foreign friend?

"Account" is a singular noun; is it correct that a singular noun follows zero-article? Or should I use "accounts"?

Comment: ...and it should be "to receive money from" without "the" in this use.

Comment: "type of account", but the grammar book says that a countable singular noun must follow an article,

Comment: @Barmar: If multiple, shouldn't "type" be pluralized, rather than "account"? I guess it depends on the contextual assumption that multiple accounts = multiple types, or multiple accounts = multiple accounts of the same type?

Comment: @Flater That's exactly right.

Comment: @Barmar: Actually, the fact that you are opening just one account is utterly irrelevant.  It would be perfectly correct, for example, to refer to "two types of animal", "three types of chair", etc.

Comment: @rjpond But if you're just buying one chair, it can't be "three types of chair". You could say "Which of the three types of chair should I buy?", but not "which types of chair should I buy".

Comment: @Barmar: True.  But if you needed to open two accounts then, even if the two accounts needed to be of different types, you could still say "which types of account".

Comment: @rjpond, you are incorrect.  You would not say "two types of animal."  You would say, "two types of animals."  The same for chair.  "Why type of account" or "which types of accounts," you can't mix them.  However, the issue here isn't plurality, it's when you can or cannot drop redundant articles.

Comment: You can say "which type of accounts" if contextually the multiple accounts must be of the same type.

Comment: @JBH: You are incorrect.  "Two types of animal" and "two types of animals" are both used; personally I find the latter more colloquial.  "*Kinds, sorts, types* and even *varieties* can all be used interchangeably (although *varieties* may be used more in more scientific sorts of contexts, e.g. **varieties of tomato**)... *Sort of / kind of / type of* are **usually followed by an uncountable noun or a singular countable noun with no article**" ( http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv310.shtml ).

Answer (score 7):

Your sentence uses the partitive preposition "of" ([read here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitive)).

"of" is a very complicatated word as it serves a great many purposes.  It is technically grammatically correct to say,

> Which type of an account...

But that sounds very formal to native English speakers.  This is because the article "an" is redundant.  The reason it's redundant is because the compound phrase, "type of account" is a compound noun.  The compound noun gets (as needed) the article, not necessarily the subordinate noun.  For example:

> I have one type of account.
>
> I have the type of account that doesn't earn interest.
>
> I have some type of account, but I don't remember which.
>
> "Interest bearing" is a type of account, but it's not the type I need.

Note, however, that deciding whether or not an article is redundant is complicated (and probably has no specific rule).  For example, you cannot drop the article  "the" in the following statement:

> That's half of the problem....

But you can drop the "of"...

> That's half the problem....

But, to answer your question, your proposed sentence is fine.  Please do not pluralize "account" nor add additional articles.

Comment: No where in your link is "of" defined as an article. It's functioning as a Partitive but it still is a preposition.

Comment: @eques, thanks for pointing that out.  I'm afraid I had articles on the brain.  I repaired the answer.